# How to index state history table

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Imagine three tables, an Order table with a status history table.

```
Order:
 Id int (PK)
 Name varchar
 OrderDate datetime

OrderHistory:
 Id int (PK)
 Order_Id int (FK)
 OrderStatus_Id int (FK)
 StatusDate datetime

OrderStatus:
 Id int (PK)
 Name varchar
```

On a status change on Order, a new record will be inserted in OrderHistory.

I query these tables to get Orders that are in a specific status for a specific amount of time.

```
select * from 
Order o
join (select Order_Id, max(StatusDate) MaxDate
      from OrderHistory oh
      group by oh.Order_Id
    ) as mx on max.Order_Id = o.Id
join OrderHistory oh on oh.Order_Id = o.Id and mx.MaxDate = oh.StatusDate
join OrderStatus os on os.Id = oh.OrderStatus_Id
where
  os.Id in (1,3,4,6,7,15,18,19)
and o.OrderDate < dateadd(month, -2, getutcdate())
```

I want to add the right indexes to the tables.
I was thinking about indexing:

- Order.OrderDate
- OrderHistory.{Order_Id, OrderStatus_Id} (combined index).

Are these the right indexes?

Comment: I'd also consider OrderHistory(Order_Id, StatusDate).

Comment: "Are these the right indexes?" - are this and other queries performing adequately? If so, yes, they'll do. If not, clearly not. Only you can define what performance is acceptable to you. Don't assume that there's a perfect set of indexes that you have to find. Usually you'll want to optimize a fuller workload than a single query though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would write the query as:

```
select *
from Order o join
     (select oh.*,
             max(StatusDate) over (partition by order_id) as MaxDate
      from OrderHistory oh
     ) oh
     on oh.Order_Id = o.Id and oh.MaxDate = oh.StatusDate join
     OrderStatus os
     on os.Id = oh.OrderStatus_Id
where os.Id in (1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 15, 18, 19) and
      o.OrderDate < dateadd(month, -2, getutcdate());
```

For this query, I would suggest:

- `order(orderdate, id)`
- `order_history(order_id, statusdate, orderstatus_id)`
- `orderstatus(id)`

I assume you have the last index because `id` should be declared as the primary key.

Note:  This query presumably returns lots and lots of data -- most orders older than 2 months (unless the statuses are highly selective).  That will slow down any query.

EDIT:

Another way to phrase this with the same indexes is:

```
select *
from Order o join
     OrderHistory oh
     on oh.Order_Id = o.Id join
     OrderStatus os
     on os.Id = oh.OrderStatus_Id
where os.Id in (1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 15, 18, 19) and
      o.OrderDate < dateadd(month, -2, getutcdate()) and
      oh.StatusDate = (select max(oh2.StatusDate)
                       from OrderHistory oh2
                       where oh2.OrderId = oh.OrderId and
                      );
```

With indexes, correlated subqueries can be quite efficient.

Comment: Getting: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'. on line 'on oh.Order_Id = o.Id and oh.MaxDate = oh.StatusDate join'

But fixed it.

Comment: Query using the partition by takes 17 seconds to complete, the old query takes 3 seconds. Results are the same. So think the old one is faster somehow

Comment: @Dennis . . . That is interesting.  I could see that happening if there are many, many rows per order in the history table.